# How should RPY converted from an IMU look like?

Tags: ros, imu, quaternion, yaw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What angles should be there?

0°-360° ?

-180° - 0° - 180° ?

Or something else?

I am for example using this code and I am getting weired results...

```
void cb_imu(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr &msg)
{
    double roll, pitch, yaw;

    tf::Quaternion q;
    tf::quaternionMsgToTF(msg->orientation, q);
    tf::Matrix3x3(q).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
}
ROS_INFO_STREAM("RPY: "<<roll*180.0/M_PI<<" "<<pitch*180.0/M_PI<<" "<<yaw*180.0/M_PI);
```

My Results of YAW show two times zero, for one half of the circle the values are negative (go up to -40°) and for the other half the same for positive values.

Regards,

Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212100/how-should-rpy-converted-from-an-imu-look-like?/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried around and got a suitable calibration for it.

Now I think it should be -180° - 0° 180° degree.

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0